# How would I drop the last x characters of a string as a python generator while using calls to iter and while?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator

I’m having trouble writing a generator function that takes an iterable and one more parameter which is an integer x. It outputs every value except for the last x values. It doesn’t know how to count how many values the iterable outputs.

I don’t know how to do this using  a while loop as well as iter. I also need to use a comprehension that creates a list to store x values at most.

Lets say we call :

```
for i in func_function(“abcdefghijk”,5):
print(i,end =”)
```

It should print `abcdef`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
def func_function(iterable, x):
    while True:
        l = []
        for x in iter(iterable):
            if len(x) == x:
               yield x
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to turn this from lookahead into lookbehind.

I'd do this by iterating over the input and maintaining a window of the most recent `n` elements:

```
def except_last_n(iterable, n):
  last_n = []
  for val in iterable:
    last_n.append(val)
    if len(last_n) > n:
      yield last_n.pop(0)

for val in except_last_n(range(10), 3):
  print(val)
```

Rewriting this as a `while` loop and `iter` is left as exercise for the reader.

```
def except_last_n(iterable, n):
  last_n = [val for val in iterable]
  if len(last_n) > n:
      yield last_n.pop(0)
```

Comment: how can you do this with a while loop and iter?

Comment: can we rewrite so that there is a list comprehension>?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @sparklecoding: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a "please code this up for me" site. We are happy to help, but you're expected to invest some effort too.

Comment: no like is it possible? i don't know if that can even be done

Comment: @sparklecoding: Yes, it can be done, and is pretty straightforward. The code I wrote for you gets you 90% there.

Comment: def except_last_n(iterable, n):
  
  last_n = [val for val in iterable]
    
    if len(last_n) > n:
      yield last_n.pop(0)

Comment: is it like that? i edited it and its on the bottom of original

Comment: can you do yield last_n[0]? instead of pop

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import deque

def drop_last_few(iterable, x=5):
    it = iter(iterable)
    data = deque(maxlen=x)
    data.extend([next(it) for i in range(x)])
    for val in it:
        yield data[0]
        data.append(val)
```

This uses a double-ended queue as storage to cache at most `x` elements. Demo:

```
>>> print(*drop_last_few("abcdefghijk", 5))
a b c d e f
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are sliceable:

```
def func_function(iterable, x):
    yield from iterable[:-x]

print(func_function("asdfgkjbewqrfgkjb",8))

k = list(func_function("asdfgkjbewqrfgkjb",8))    
print(k) # ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'j', 'b', 'e']
```

The while loop, iter and `l=[]` are not needed...

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes the iterable supports slicing, which it may or may not do.

Comment: doesn't support slicing

Comment: @NPE - the OP askes for strings - strings are sliceable.

Comment: @sparklecoding strings support slicing